# Automated performance tests

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, performance-testing

At our company we have unit tests.
We are thinking of writing some automated performance tests that will also be part of the test suite, so that both developers and the automated build will run them. The tests will do something and then fail if it took more than some pre-estimated time.

The problem is, different computers have different CPU speeds, and also processes running in the background can slow down execution. So how should we go about these tests?

Comment: What kind of application is this? - web, desktop ...

Answer (score 2):

One strategy is to design your performance metrics for the best machine that code will run on; as long as it runs fast enough on worse machines, you're guaranteed to have better performance in production. Basically, include a fudge factor knowing that it will have to run on slower machines, presumably during testing/development.

Another strategy is to do some benchmarking during your test setup, and use that time amount as your "unit time" instead of using seconds. For example, calculating the 20th Fibonacci number using the dog-slow recursive algorithm, and then saying that all the tests have to run within 10 "20-fibs", so while the wall-clock time is going to be slower on slow machines, you have a machine-independant metric for how well it's running.

Processes running in the background is harder. Obviously you usually don't want other things interfering with your test, so one strategy is to try and eliminate that as much as possible - regular developers can probably kill some processes and run again if there's a failure, and your continuous integration box should be kept relatively clear.

If that doesn't work, or isn't good enough, you could try the opposite approach: run a bunch of CPU/IO intensive processes at the same time as your tests to mimic an overloaded system, and if the tests pass with that environment, the performance should be fine in a normal system

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the limiting resource of your program (I/O, CPU, memory), you can get good results with measuring the used CPU time and comparing it to the system speed. For example, the performance tests for my current program obtain the spent CPU time with `time` and get the CPU speed from `/proc/cpuinfo` to measure the number of cycles spent for a computation.

This approach has two caveats: Firstly, it does not measure the achieved parallelity, and secondly, it does not measure external performance factors like I/O usage.

Answer (score 1):

If the idea is to understand how code changes affect performance and ensure that the performance is greater than or equal to previous builds then you need to run the tests on a known hardware profile every time.  The most accurate way to do this would be to set up a machine(s) that you use for your testing every single time the tests are executed.  If many developers need to do this, sometimes simultaneously, perhaps creating a VM image that they could spin up and point to for the tests to execute on would be worthwhile.

You should not run these on the developers boxes themselves because as you mentioned all kinds of factors could affect the outcome of the tests on those boxes.

You should avoid trying to measure performance while under load/strain from outside of the system being tested, (low disk space, network bandwidth, memory, cpu, etc) unless those conditions are specifically set up as part of the test case.  For instance, you can have 3 different test runs, one while the machine is under no load, another where you are under medium load (simulating other programs running in the background) and another under high load.

You can also run tests on various hardware profiles as part of your other stress/performance tests but you probably won't get much value out of running them against every build.  Again, however, if you want you could do a few different test runs against different hardware profiles, this requires more setup though since you would need additional machines and/or VM images set up and the infrastructure to kick off the tests against these machines, gather the results and report on them.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for Sam's response. I've done this a number of times in the past and it's critical to lock down your performance test environment and ensure you're minimizing any potential flux.

Running the tests on devs' systems may be a useful flag for individual devs, but having a central system to run the tests on is critical. One caveat about doing this in VMs: ensure you understand the load on the VM *host* system because load there can impact performance in the hosted VMs.

I've had the best, most consistent and useful results when I ran these sorts of suites during a nightly smoke check build.

Answer (score 0):

It is also a question about tolerances (or acceptable capacity ranges) that will make your tests valid. Ideally, as has been stated, you need a predictable, stable and consistent set up for any useful comparison. That said if you understand the basic operational ranges of the SUT (CPU available, Mem Available etc.) then early developer testing can be done on a mix and match of systems and conditions that are within the known resource tolerances.